# Filling javascript array with random numbers is crashing browser

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript functions intending to simulate dice rolls from D&D type games.

The first function, getRandom(), takes in a low number and a high number and spits back a random integer between the two numbers.

```
function getRandom(low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
}
```

The second function, dropLow(), is supposed to roll the dice four times, drop the lowest scoring dice and add up the remaining three. As long as the total is greater than 9, it will return the total.

```
function dropLow() {
    var rolls = [],
        lowest,
        total;
    do {
        total = 0;
        for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
            rolls.push(getRandom(1,6));
            total += rolls[x];
        }
        lowest = rolls[0];
        for (x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
            if (rolls[x] < lowest) {
                lowest = rolls[x];
            }
        }
        total -= lowest;
    } while (total < 10);
    rolls.length = 0;
    return total;
}
```

If I only call dropLow() once, everything works great. But the more I call it, the more frequently my browser (Chrome) freaks out and crashes (The specific error is: "Aw Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage. To continue, reload or go to another page."). I thought maybe some setting in my browser was causing the problem, so I pulled the page up on a tablet and it still froze/crashed. Pulled up firefox and same issue occurs.

I've looked into destroying the array, or at least clearing out its contents, on the off chance that I was continuously building on the original, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Can anyone help me figure out how or why this is happening?

Comment: I would like to reccomend people, to not invent the whell.
There is a very goold library for that ChanceJS: chancejs.com.

Comment: @Amina But that wheel is 12 inches in diameter and I need one that's 4 inches. One library does not fit all, and it's good to be able to do things yourself too.

Comment: Why are you doing `rolls.length = 0;`?

Comment: You right, this is why I didn't post it as an answer, just a comment. I think you or other viewers may like it

Comment: @meagar I did rolls.length = 0; as an attempt to clear out the array because I thought it might have been building up and up and up. That wasn't the case, but I left it in because I didn't figure it was hurting anything to destroy the array when I was done with it.

Comment: @Nick It hurts in that it's a weird line of non-idiomatic code that *doesn't do anything*. Somebody (maybe you) will come across that line of code and waste a bunch of time trying to figure out why it's there. They'll assume that it *must* be important, because why else would it have been left in the codebase? They'll probably leave it alone, because they're not *completely* sure it's unnecessary, and it will sit there until the *next* developer finds it and wastes a bunch of time trying to figure out why it's there.

Comment: @meagar Fair enough. I pulled it. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `for (x = 0` creates a global variable *x*, you should keep variables local: `for (var x = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `rolls = []` inside the `do` loop.

Since you aren't resetting the array, you are using old values. If the `do..while` loop runs twice, then it's using the same low values all the time, causing a crash.